# Node process.hrtime() is five years off?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apple-m1

I'm using Node v16.17 on MacBook Pro M1.
I want to use microsecond timestamps, so I tried `process.hrtime()`.
But this is very strange, as the first array element (which should be seconds when multiplied by 1000) is like some date in 2017:

```
> new Date().getTime();
1669997280728
> process.hrtime();
[ 1486038, 90680583 ]
```

So, if I take 1486038000 --> it is Thu, 02 Feb 2017 12:20:00 GMT
If I take out the milliseconds from new Date().getTime() -> it is correctly Fri, 02 Dec 2022 16:08:00 GMT

What it the issue here? I thought process.hrtime() will be the high resolution time, but why is this so *off*?

Thanks
Fritz

Comment: I'm getting `[ 4493897, 925045375 ]` on my M1 MacBook Pro

Comment: As far as I remember hrtime returns the value from the last time hrtime has been called, hence the result. Please check https://nodejs.org/api/process.html -> `time <integer[]> The result of a previous call to process.hrtime()` and `The primary use is for measuring performance between intervals:`

Comment: `I want to use microsecond timestamps` for what purpose do you need this?

Comment: Alright, so as I understand, process.hrtime is not usable as timestamp replacement.
Our usecase is: we are receiving signals from an external device, where we are processing > 1 signal / ms. That's why we were thinking of using microseconds to assign them to a high resolution timestamp. I guess we cannot do that with reasonable effort then?
Thanks

Comment: @fritz Why don't you assign an ever increasing number to each signal? Does it have to be time related? If it's time related you _may_ get away with setting a reference point first `let ref = process.hrtime()` and then later `let timestamp = process.hrtime(ref)` this way, the timestamp will be relative to the time and date by the first `process.hrtime()` (`ref` variable) call.

Comment: I don't know the upper limit of `process.hrtime()` (what the time between two calls can be at most) but this is how you would use it to benchmark your code. So it's a very similar use case.

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs,

> These times are relative to an arbitrary time in the past, and not related to the time of day and therefore not subject to clock drift. The primary use is for measuring performance between intervals
>
> https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processhrtimetime

It is only a coincidence that you got a somewhat relevant date.

You should be using `process.hrtime.bigint()`, however, because `process.hrtime()` has been [legacy](/questions/tagged/legacy) for a while (even in Node v16.17).

Answer (score 1):

What?

[`process.hrtime()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processhrtimetime) has ***nothing*** do to with the real-time clock, as is explained by the docs:

> These times are relative to an **arbitrary time in the past**, and not related to the time of day and therefore not subject to clock drift.

(emphasis mine)

And,

> The primary use is for measuring performance between intervals: